# How do you convert pygame game into a swf file?

Tags: python, flash, pygame

I would like to have my pygame game converted into a swf file, but i have no idea how.

I do know there is a module called pyswf, but I have no idea how to use it.

Could somebody please help me?

(Edit: What about a exe to swf convertor? If there is one, i could just use pyinstaller first and then the exe to swf convertor.)

Comment: @hi Owen, welcome to stackoverflow!  You can start by reading the docs: https://github.com/timknip/pyswf/tree/master/docs and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That module is for reading and writing swf files. There is no automated way to convert Python code into Flash/ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you convert pygame game into a swf file?

You don't. There's no way to convert a pygame application to a flash application, except for a complete rewrite.

P.S.: It's 2019. Flash is dead. Maybe you have more luck with [Pyjsdl](https://gatc.ca/projects/pyjsdl/).